# How to choose the best duration time for a survey

Tags: sampling, simulation, analytical

To analyse the traffic of passengers using an elevator of 8 floors with one main entrance, I need to register the number of passengers entering and quiting the elevator and also the waiting time.
Since I have one person to collect these data, a proposed solution is to measure the traffic in a given floor for a duration of for example 10 minutes, then move to the next floor and measure the traffic again, this from 7:00 am to 7:00 pm.

My main concern is how to choose the duration time (here 10 minutes) so I am conducting a  simulation using systematic sampling for each duration: 1, 2, 3,.., 15 minutes, and then compare the bias of each duration.
My question is in two points : 
- How much this procedure is reliable ?
- Is there an analytical method to measure the reliability of this method of sampling ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Put the observer inside the elevator. (S)he can then record the numbers and times of all people entering the elevator on any floor. The waitings times can roughly be estimated from that and changes in use intensity over the day can be measured precisely.

Comment: It is a good idea in fact. But our main concern is the waiting time, not the behaviour of the passengers. Plus it is probably hard to register data inside the elevator.

Comment: Use MIT AppInventor to write a little app and all the observer has to do is type numbers of entering and leaving people into a tablet computer or mobile phone. It takes one or two weekends to learn AppInventor and write that app. Nobody on the 10th floor waits longer for the elevator than the time in between two stops of that elevator in the 10th floor. If the elevator is in constant use, mean and median waiting time will be half of the time between the two stops on that floor and if the elevator is not in use (waiting at some floor) the observer can note that too.

Comment: >  If the elevator is in constant use, mean and median waiting time will be half of the time -------- the waiting times will be roughly uniformely distributed between those two values which opens the door to simulation.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution to measure the traffic in a given floor for some time and then move to the next floor already seems wrong, as it assumes that traffic flow is constant on all floors, which is not the case (unless you are surveying a very strange building).

For example, consider a typical office building, where majority of workers go to lunch just before 12. If you survey floor 5 from 11:50 to 12:00, you will see a lot of traffic, way more than on the floor 3, which you surveyed from 11:30 to 11:40. Even though very likely both floors have similar amount of traffic.

A correct survey procedure should take such variability during the day into account.

Comment: If I think this answer through, I think the problem does not lie with 'measuring the traffic in a given floor for some time and then move to the next floor', but with the proposed lengths of 'some time'. Measuring only 15 minutes will indeed give the problems alluded to in this answer (it might not even be enough for the elevator to get to a certain floor). A day per time period, (i.e. a couple of days per floor, one week per floor perhaps) on the other hand, just might be enough though, and would solve the concerns stated in this answer.

Comment: Well that is probably what I would if I had as many ressources in time, money and persons as necessay to register the data. But I have not,  and must evaluate the sampling quality.

Comment: @IWS speding a day or two per floor would indeed be reasonable, and that's what I meant by 'taking variability during the day' into account. As I understood from the question Mamoun want's to spend one day in total moving between the floors, and that does not sound like a good idea. 

To answer the last Mamoun's comment, I'm afraid you will not be able to evaluate the sampling quality in a rigorous manner, and even if you manage, the outcome I would expect is 'poor'.